# How to filter comments by type?

Tags: wordpress

I want to filter comments type because I use Sensei of WooThemes and this plugin logs the activity in comments, and the Sensei comments appear with regular comments.

I put the argument 'type' in get_comments without success.

Comment: Did you read http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments?

Comment: This person probably did.  But I find the codex lacks guidance for things that demand more customized approaches. So it sounds like the OP really needs an inner join between comments and some other plugin's tables to filter by type.  This shouldn't be hard, but in WP land, it can be difficult.  I've had to do it before by adding a custom wp_query for $comments to the comments-template.php (list_comments) in wp-includes.  NOT ideal.  I had to hack the core.  If anyone has a better way to construct an inner join by passing args from a filter or something, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 1):

you can use **wp_list_comments** instead of **get_comments**
read the documentation :  http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_comments

filter comment by type "comment", the default is all :

```
<?php wp_list_comments( array( 'type' => 'comment', 'callback' => 'my_theme_comments', 'style' => 'ol' ) ); ?>
```

it's work for me, and hope this help someone.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using `get_comments()` then you  can simply use `$comment->comment_type` to check for only empty types (normal comments)